# Is there a way to get the Generic Type from an Extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, generic-programming

Consider this method:

```
public static TResult CastTo<T, TResult>(this T arg)
        {
            TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            bool? converter = typeConverter?.CanConvertTo(typeof(TResult));
            if (converter != null && converter == true)
                return (TResult)typeConverter.ConvertTo(arg, typeof(TResult));
            else
                return default(TResult);
        }
```

Is there a way to set the generic type from the extension method, I mean, Instead to call:

```
 string s = "1";
 s.CastTo<string, int>();
```

Something to get the input type directly from the class who's calling. I'm pretty new with C# and I want to know this issue.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The problem is to explicity declare the type of the input, I want to know if there is a way to take it inplicity from the class who call the extension method

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you mean without having to do `string s = "1"`, or you want to get the type of `s`?

Comment: Is not exactly about the method, is an example, I want to know if there is a way to inplicit set the string type as the input generic type.

Comment: Is your question about having `s.CastTo<int>();` instead of `s.CastTo<string, int>();`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's the point.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the type of `T`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ommit the type when your generic method returns nothing:

```
public static void CastTo<T, TResult>(this T arg, out TResult var)
{
    TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
    bool? converter = typeConverter?.CanConvertTo(typeof(TResult));
    if (converter != null && converter == true)
        var = (TResult)typeConverter.ConvertTo(arg, typeof(TResult));
    else
        var = default(TResult);
}
```

And you use it like so:

```
string s = "1";
int i;
s.CastTo(out i);
```

It will know both the base type and output type without having to explicitely name them.

Comment: @JosbelLunaRodríguez - You know that if you change the `typeof(T)` to `arg.GetType()` that you can than change the signature of the method to `TResult CastTo<TResult>(this object arg)` which would be a far more natural way to call this method. There is no advantage to specifying `T` as a generic parameter whatsoever and now you are forced to use an out parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Use object type:

```
    public static TResult CastTo<TResult>(this object arg)
    {
        TypeConverter typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(arg.GetType());
        bool? converter = typeConverter.CanConvertTo(typeof(TResult));
        if (converter != null && converter == true)
            return (TResult)typeConverter.ConvertTo(arg, typeof(TResult));
        else
            return default(TResult);
    }
```

Comment: In this way works, but is not exactly about the method, is an example, I want to know if there is a way to inplicit set the string type as the input generic type. For example, I could need to declare a variable with the input type T, an I think in this way is impossible.

Comment: @JosbelLunaRodríguez I don't understand you. you say "set the string type as the input generic type". what doues it mean? `(this string arg)`? or `(this T arg) where T:string`?

Comment: I can use it as, `int.CastTo<int,string>()`, or `string.CastTo<string, int>()`, etc. But when I call this, i have to explicity write the int, or string respectively, I'm not sure if there is a way to avoid it, and use something like string.CastTo<int> or `int.CastTo<string>()` ,

Comment: @JosbelLunaRodríguez - This is the correct way to do it. Starting with `object` means it can be any type. All you should really be concerned with is the output type. If `T` can be constrained then the type of `arg` can be the constrained type. That's how `Cast<T>()` works in LINQ - it's constrained to `IEnumerable` (rather than just `object`).